# Throwing a exception with custom message from Mockito Junit testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

```
try {
        response = restTemplate.postForEntity(endPoint, request, Object.class);
        lOGGER.info("response is " + response);
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        lOGGER.error("Exception :" + e.getMessage());
        if ((e.getMessage().contains("401") || e.getMessage().contains("Unauthorized")) ) {
            ServiceImpl.evictTokenCache("authToken");
            getData(requestDto);
        } else {
            throw new CustomException(e.getMessage());
        }
```

above is my service and trying to write test case for catch clause,and my test case is

```
@Test()
public void getExceptionTest() throws Exception {
    RequestDto requestDto = new RequestDto();
    requestDto.setPage("1");
    AuthConfig authDTO = new AuthConfig();
    authDTO.setUrl("Url");
    Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenThrow((new Exception("Unauthorized")));
    ResponseDTO response = restCallUtil.getData(requestDto);
    assertNull(response);
}
```

what i am trying to do incatch block is,when ever i get Unauthorized exception i am clearing the cache and calling the same method again. So in order to test catch block from my test class i am trying to throw exception with message as "Unauthorized ",but when i run test case i am getting

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
> Checked exception is invalid for this method!
> Invalid: java.lang.Exception: Unauthorized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to note is that an instance of `Exception` which is not also an instance of `RuntimeException` is a **checked** exception. Thus, the only way the for a method to throw a generic `Exception` is for the method signature to contain "`throws Exception`" or "`throws Throwable`".

So.. why are you getting this error? You are stubbing the `postForEntity` method which throws `RestClientException`, and `Exception` is not an instance of `RestClientException`. Thus, your stubbing is invalid.

If you want to stub the method such that the catch block for the generic case is entered, you will need to throw a `RuntimeException`, which is **unchecked**, and therefore not subject to the "throws" restriction.

That said, it would be probably be wiser to simply catch only the RestClientException in the original method. If there is some RuntimeException you want to catch, then you would hopefully already be aware of what that is and catch it specifically.